# (Playwirght) Automation of actions is not working

Tags: python, playwright

I have written a code using **playwright** that automate some actions in aliexpress website.

**Website**:
https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=AS_20220518080059&SearchText=makeup

Here is the **script** I wrote to automate the action of changing the country before parsing the site data

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def main():
    
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = browser.new_context()
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto("https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=AS_20220518080059&SearchText=makeup")
        countrySwitcher = page.query_selector("#switcher-info")
        countrySwitcher.click()
        page.locator("a:has-text(\"Morocco\")").click()
        page.locator("[placeholder=\"Search\"]").first.click()
        page.locator("[placeholder=\"Search\"]").first.fill("Spain")
        page.locator("li:has-text(\"Spain\")").click()
        page.locator("span:has-text(\"Español\")").click()
        page.locator("text=English").nth(1).click()
        page.locator("span:has-text(\"EUR ( Euro )\")").click()
        page.locator("text=EUR ( Euro ) CHF ( Swiss Franc ) MXN ( Mexican Peso ) EUR ( Euro ) CLP ( Chilean >> [placeholder=\"Search\"]").click()
        page.locator("text=EUR ( Euro ) CHF ( Swiss Franc ) MXN ( Mexican Peso ) EUR ( Euro ) CLP ( Chilean >> [placeholder=\"Search\"]").fill("MAD")
        page.locator("text=MAD ( Moroccan Dirham )").click()
        with page.expect_navigation():
            page.locator("text=Save").click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But the code doesn't work and diplay me this error in my console :

```
  File "C:\Users\aicha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 63, in inner_send    
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "a:has-text("Morocco")"
============================================================
```

I think the code stops compiling when it gets to this line `countrySwitcher = page.query_selector("#switcher-info")`
But I really don't know the reason why. I will appreciate any help from you to fix this issue because I am pretty new in using playwright.
Thank you !

Comment: It is `from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright` without `m` at the end!

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with the problem, it is just a typo. Then, I have edited my question

Comment: Have you any idea to help please

Comment: What is the expected action from the above code?

Comment: To change the coutry that figures in the dropdown in the top of the website

Comment: Any idea to help please??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def main():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = browser.new_context()
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto("https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=AS_20220518080059&SearchText=makeup")
        countrySwitcher = page.query_selector("#switcher-info")
        countrySwitcher.click()
        # time.sleep(6000)
        page.locator("#nav-global > div.ng-item-wrap.ng-item.ng-switcher.active > div > div > div > div.switcher-shipto.item.util-clearfix > div").click()
        page.locator("[placeholder=\"Search\"]").first.click()
        page.locator("[placeholder=\"Search\"]").first.fill("Spain")
        page.locator("li:has-text(\"Spain\")").click()
        page.locator("span:has-text(\"Español\")").click()
        page.locator("text=English").nth(1).click()
        page.locator("span:has-text(\"EUR ( Euro )\")").click()
        page.locator(
            "text=EUR ( Euro ) CHF ( Swiss Franc ) MXN ( Mexican Peso ) EUR ( Euro ) CLP ( Chilean >> [placeholder=\"Search\"]").click()
        page.locator(
            "text=EUR ( Euro ) CHF ( Swiss Franc ) MXN ( Mexican Peso ) EUR ( Euro ) CLP ( Chilean >> [placeholder=\"Search\"]").fill(
            "MAD")
        page.locator("text=MAD ( Moroccan Dirham )").click()
        with page.expect_navigation():
            page.locator("button", has_text="Save").click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem was that you were searching specifically for the text "Morocco" to be present. It would not have been there if you were from another country since alibaba uses country detection. Your last code line, i.e. `page.locator("text=Save").click()` was also faulty. The text "Save" resided inside a descendant element which you need to account for.

In general, it is always a good idea to make your locaters as general and flexible as possible to account for minor website changes done by the admin. Therefore, instead of using text to find the elements, maybe you should try using CSS selectors instead?

Further [reading](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/selectors)